# add borders to sides of screen in css

Tags: html, css

This is basically what I am trying to do:

**Step 1** have a HTML file with elements:

[example image of HTML file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0ct7Q.png)

**Step 2** (add borders to the side of the screen):

[Same file with borders on sides](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FjDJP.png).

(code of the HTML file):

```
<a>hello</a>
```

I attempted to use `divs` on the sides of the screen, that didn't work.

I also attempted to put my elements inside of a div and use the `aspect-ratio` property to try and have the same effect, that didn't work.

Hope this all makes sense.

Comment: Are you wanting actual borders or are you just trying to center the hello div within the page, perhaps with some colored background at the sides.?

Comment: @AHaworth I am wanting actual borders.

Comment: So you'd use the CSS border property with for example border-width: 0 33%; See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/web/css/border Make sure that box-sizing is set to content-box not border-box (which subsumes border width into the overall element width).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example with `flex` :

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      .flex {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: space-between;
      }
      /* Define the styles for the page borders */
      .border-left {
        width: 33%;
        height: 100vh;
        background-color: black;
      }
      .border-right {
        width: 33%;
        height: 100vh;
        background-color: black;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="flex">
    <div class="border-left"></div>
      <div><h1>content</h1></div>
    <div class="border-right"></div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just set the body background and reduce the size of a. Something like this.

```
body {
  background-color: grey;
}

a {
  width: 33%;
  margin: auto;
}
```

In the future, you should replace a with a div with a container class or something like that.

Comment: If I am dealing with multiple elements such as 6 ```<a>hello</a><p>hello</p>``` would I put the ```width: 33%; margin: auto; ``` in each element's style attribute?

Comment: You would put all of those elements inside a <div> element and put the css onto that div element.

Answer (score 0):

```css
.main{
    border-right: 25px solid black;
    border-left: 25px solid black;
    height: 100vh
}

.container{
  height: 300px;
  text-align: center
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="container">
  this is container
  </div>
</div>
```